# removing listview items which are blank when first listview item is removed

Tags: listview

I have a listvew with an item added to it.  I also have two additional items added underneath the first item, but those two items have a "" value for the item value, and only have values in the subitems columns.  What I'm looking for is how to remove all the items which have no "item" value when the first item (which has an item value) is removed.  The picture can better explain.  Thank you for your help!  Remove NO Ketchup, No Lettuce when Cheeseburger is removed, and leave coke intact.

[IMG]http://i.imgur.com/3hUSVHp.png[/IMG]

Answer (score 0):

according to me for better representation for this functionality, you should use expandable listview. in the child you can show ketchup and other details. and when you will delete the cheesebustor it will automatically delete the subitems. so try your best and let me know if i can help you better.